# Problem to realise a frequency band sweeper with GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio

I am very new to GNU Radio, and I am stumbling to realise a periodic frequency band sweeper.

The idea is as follow:
given a sampling rate `samp_rate`, a start frequency `f_start`, a stop frequency `f_stop`, a number of channels `n_channels`, and a sweep rate `sweep_rate`, I would like to go from `f_start` to `f_stop` periodically at a rate given by `sweep_rate` (meaning having `sweep_rate` repetitions `f_start -> ... -> f_stop -> f_start -> ...` every second).

So far, I managed to have a periodic repetition with the embedded python code here below

```
"""
Embedded Python Blocks:

Each time this file is saved, GRC will instantiate the first class it finds
to get ports and parameters of your block. The arguments to __init__  will
be the parameters. All of them are required to have default values!
"""

import numpy as np
from gnuradio import gr
import pmt


class blk(gr.sync_block): # other base classes are basic_block, decim_block, interp_block
    """!
    Embedded Python Block
    Function changing periodically the signal source's frequency, from
    f_min to f_max, by step of BW_per_channel [i.e. (f_max-f_min)/(n_channels-1)]

    Input:
    ------
    n_channels: <class int> (default: 3)
        Number of frequencies (called channels)

    samp_rate: <class float> (default: 32e3)
        Number of samples to have 1 second

    sweep_rate: <classs int> (default: 1)
        Number of total bandwidth sweepings per second

    f_start: <class float> (default: 2.4e3)
        First channel

    f_stop: <class float> (default: 2.5e3)
        Last channel
    """

    def __init__(self, n_channels=3, samp_rate=32e3, sweep_rate=1, f_start=2.4e3, f_stop=2.5e3): # only default arguments here
        """arguments to this function show up as parameters in GRC"""
        gr.sync_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='Frequency sweeper', # will show up in GRC
            in_sig=[np.float32],
            out_sig=[]
        )
        # if an attribute with the same name as a parameter is found,
        # a callback is registered (properties work, too).
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate
        self.sweep_rate = sweep_rate
        self.f_start = f_start
        self.f_stop = f_stop

        self.BW_tot = self.f_stop - f_start

        self.frequencies = [self.f_start + i*self.BW_tot/(self.n_channels-1) for i in range(self.n_channels)]

        self.counter = 0 # if bigger than given threshold, update the frequency
        self.i = 0 # which frequency to select

        self.t_per_freq = self.samp_rate/self.sweep_rate/self.n_channels

        self.outPortFreq = "frequency"
        self.message_port_register_out(pmt.intern(self.outPortFreq))
        self.outPortDebugMsg = "debug"
        self.message_port_register_out(pmt.intern(self.outPortDebugMsg))



    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        """!
        Example: change frequency of signal source periodically
        """

        # Create dictionaries to send messages to source and terminal
        dict_debug = pmt.make_dict()
        dict_msg = pmt.make_dict()

        # Some debug messages sent to the terminal
        dict_debug = pmt.dict_add(dict_debug, pmt.intern("t_per_freq"), pmt.from_double(self.t_per_freq))
        dict_debug = pmt.dict_add(dict_debug, pmt.intern("counter"), pmt.from_double(self.counter))
        pmt_msg_debug = pmt.dict_add(dict_debug, pmt.intern(f"freq[{self.i}]"), pmt.from_double(self.frequencies[self.i]))
        self.message_port_pub(pmt.intern(self.outPortDebugMsg), pmt_msg_debug)

        self.counter = self.counter + len(input_items[0])

        if self.counter > self.t_per_freq:
            self.i += 1
            self.counter = 0

        if self.i > len(self.frequencies)-1: self.i = 0

        # Message sent to update the source frequency
        pmt_msg = pmt.dict_add(dict_msg, pmt.intern("freq"), pmt.from_double(self.frequencies[self.i]))
        self.message_port_pub(pmt.intern(self.outPortFreq), pmt_msg)

        return len(input_items[0])
```

but the sweep frequency is not correct, and I do not know why. As an example, with `n_channels = 50`, `sweep_rate = 1`, `samp_rate = 100e3`, `f_start = 2.4e3`, and `f_stop = 2.5e3`, I have the result shown in the picture.[image]
which is obviously not the result I was hoping for. Can someone help me out ? I also attach to this post the [complete .grc](https://github.com/aheuchamps/sandbox-repo/blob/main/sweep_jammer_03.grc), the [complete custom embedded Python block](https://github.com/aheuchamps/sandbox-repo/blob/main/epy_block_0.py), and the [complete Python file](https://github.com/aheuchamps/sandbox-repo/blob/main/sweep_jammer.py) for better help.

---

### Update:

I managed to have a real time modification of `sweep_rate`, but the period is still not right. Does anyone have an idea of why ? Here below is the updated code of my embedded Pyth block

```
"""
Embedded Python Blocks:

Each time this file is saved, GRC will instantiate the first class it finds
to get ports and parameters of your block. The arguments to __init__  will
be the parameters. All of them are required to have default values!
"""

import numpy as np
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.gr import log
import pmt, math


class blk(gr.sync_block): # other base classes are basic_block, decim_block, interp_block
    """!
    Embedded Python Block
    Function changing periodically the signal source's frequency, from
    f_min to f_max, by step of BW_per_channel [i.e. (f_max-f_min)/(n_channels-1)]

    Input:
    ------
    n_channels: <class int> (default: 3)
        Number of frequencies (called channels)

    samp_rate: <class float> (default: 32e3)
        Number of samples to have 1 second

    sweep_rate: <classs int> (default: 1)
        Number of total bandwidth sweepings per second

    f_start: <class float> (default: 2.4e3)
        First channel

    f_stop: <class float> (default: 2.5e3)
        Last channel
    """

    def __init__(self, n_channels=3, samp_rate=32e3, sweep_rate=1, f_start=2.4e3, f_stop=2.5e3): # only default arguments here
        """arguments to this function show up as parameters in GRC"""
        gr.sync_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='Frequency sweeper', # will show up in GRC
            in_sig=[np.float32],
            out_sig=[]
        )
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate
        self.sweep_rate = sweep_rate
        self.f_start = f_start
        self.f_stop = f_stop

        self.BW_tot = self.f_stop - f_start

        self.frequencies = [self.f_start + i*self.BW_tot/(self.n_channels-1) for i in range(self.n_channels)]

        self.counter = self.nitems_written(0) # if bigger than given threshold, update the frequency
        self.i = 0 # which frequency to select

        self.t_per_freq = self.samp_rate/self.sweep_rate/self.n_channels

        self.outPortFreq = "frequency"
        self.message_port_register_out(pmt.intern(self.outPortFreq))



    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        """!
        Example: change frequency of signal source periodically
        """

        # Create dictionary to send messages to source
        dict_msg = pmt.make_dict()

        # Some messages sent to the terminal
        log.info( f"\r \
                    \rt_per_freq={self.t_per_freq} \
                    \rcounter={self.counter} \
                    \rfreq[{self.i}]={self.frequencies[self.i]} \
                    \rsweep_rate={self.sweep_rate} \
                    \rlen(input_items[0])={len(input_items[0])}" )

        self.t_per_freq = self.samp_rate / self.sweep_rate / self.n_channels
        self.counter += len(input_items[0])

        if self.counter > self.t_per_freq:
            self.i += 1
            self.counter = 0

        if self.i > len(self.frequencies)-1: self.i = 0

        # Message sent to update the source frequency
        pmt_msg = pmt.dict_add(dict_msg, pmt.intern("freq"), pmt.from_double(self.frequencies[self.i]))
        self.message_port_pub(pmt.intern(self.outPortFreq), pmt_msg)

        return len(input_items[0])
```

Comment: instead of a `self.counter` you could use `self.nitems_written(0)`: GNU Radio already has to count the items you produced :)

Comment: instead of sending debug messages, you could use the GNU Radio logger! `from gnuradio.gr import log`, then in your `work` you could do  `log.debug("huhu")` (or `log.trace`, or `log.info` or `log.warn`)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for your answer and suggestions. I made the changes you proposed, but still the sweeping frequency is not correct (I used the same parameter set as previously). Any idea on how to correct that ?
Alex

Comment: Not sure if you have seen this, but a similar question was asked over on the ADI forums: https://ez.analog.com/wide-band-rf-transceivers/design-support/f/q-a/107548/fast-frequency-sweep-with-the-pluto-in-gnu-radio There is a part about one of the sinks you can use in a particular way.

Comment: @jdv Thank you for the pointer, I will check it. Have a nice day
Alex

Comment: @aheuchamps if that link helps, make sure you come back and self-answer! I am interested in this situation as well.

Comment: Hey @jdv I have something in which I can change the value of `sweep_rate` dynamically and effectively changes the sweeping, but the math to get the right sweeping frequency is still not correct. To do so, I just had to put the computation inside the `work()` function of the Python block, i.e. put
```self.t_per_freq = self.samp_rate / self.sweep_rate / self.n_channels``` inside it.
Any idea on how to compute the value of `t_per_freq` ? Have a nice day, Alex.

Comment: @aheuchamps that sounds like a new question. You might want to create an Answer here even if it is a partial one and see if others can add to it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @rclocher3 Hello, thank you for your greetings. Have a nice day, Alex